# Spring Repository: Returns same result list despite changing parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-repositories

I have a SpringBoot Service, with the following function:

```
public class RankingService
{
    public List<RankingDto> getIncrementralChanges(Double now, Double before)
    {
         List<RankingDto> rankingNow = createRanking(now);
         List<RankingDto> rankingBefore = createRanking(before);

         return getChanges(rankingNow, rankingBefore);
    }

    private List<RankingDto> createRanking(Double time)
    {
        return this.rankingRepo.findByTime(time)
             .stream()
             .map(e -> modelMapper.map(e, RankingDto.class))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<RankingDto> getChanges(List<RankingDto> l1, List<RankingDto> l2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But my problem is the following:

The ResultSet of "rankingNow" and "rankingBefore" is exactly the same!
I noticed in the log file, that the correct values will be binded in the sql query, so I have no idea, why the result sets are identical.

If I call the two queries in the database manually, I see the differences in both result sets.

It seems to me, that a cache or whatever kicks in, even though it seems in the log file, that both queries are really called.

If I call some native functions of the repository, e.g. findById(10) and findById(11), the result set differs, but with my custom query it doesn't.

Here is the query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Ranking JOIN r.team t JOIN t.starter s WHERE totalTime <= ?1")
@EntityGraph(attributePath = {"team", "team.starters"})
List<Ranking> findByTime(Double time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already printed the query that is executed?
In my opinion it is not passed the correct value of `time`.

---

To do a custom query with `@Query` you should refer to the parameter by position or by name, like this (note that the indexes of the method parameters start from 1):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Ranking JOIN r.team t JOIN t.starter s WHERE totalTime <= ?1")
List<Ranking> findByTime(Double time);
```

or by name:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Ranking JOIN r.team t JOIN t.starter s WHERE totalTime <= :time")
List<Ranking> findByTime(Double time);
```

See [this article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) as reference.

Comment: it's a typo. I've edited the question. I see in the log file that the passed values are correct in both cases.

Comment: Can you add to the question also the queries?